# Assigning class attributes by reference or by value?

Tags: python, variables

See this Leetcode MergeTwoSupportedList solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2):
        """
        :type list1: Optional[ListNode]
        :type list2: Optional[ListNode]
        :rtype: Optional[ListNode]
        """
        
        prehead = ListNode(-1)
        curr = prehead

        while list1 and list2:
            if (list1.val <= list2.val):
                curr.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                curr.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            curr = curr.next
        
        curr.next = list1 if list1 != None else list2

        return prehead.next
```

When we assign `curr.next = list1` and then `list1 = list1.next` right after, why does `curr.next` not point to `list1.next`? From my understanding these objects and their attributes should be mutable, which means variable assignment points to a location in memory.

To make sure I'm understanding variable assignment correctly:

```
a = []
b = [1]
a = b
b.append(2)

print(a)
print(b)

print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

In this example we can see that a == b even when we change b. How is the question above any different?

Comment: All Python variables contain references (pointers) to objects. When assigning, the reference (memory address) is copied to the target variable. In the first example the references stored in the variables are changed while in the second example `append` modifies the referenced object (the list) but not the reference to it.

Comment: Stop thinking about the *type of object* when it comes to the semantics fo assignment - assignment **always works exactly the same way regardless of type**. Python variables/attributes are *references to objects*. There is no such distinction as "assigning attributes by value or by reference". There is only one way that this works in Python. Python assigns *an object* to an attribute.

Comment: When you do: `curr.next = list1` this *mutates the object being referenced by `curr`*, assigning the object that happens to be referenced by `list1` *at that moment* to the `.next` attribute. Then, the line `list1 = list1.next` assigns *the object being referenced by `list1`'s `.next` attribute to the local variable `list1`. Nowhere does it mutate the object being referenced by `curr`. Normal assignment to a variable **never mutates**. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

> When we assign `curr.next = list1` and then `list1 = list1.next` right after, why does `curr.next` not point to `list1.next`?

Every Python variable contains a reference, in reality. You've done the following:

1. Copy into `curr.next` there reference *currently* contained by `list1`
2. Replace `list1`'s reference with one to `list1.next`

In that order. So, changing the value of `list1` can't have any effect on `curr.next`.

Now, if in "2" you had instead manipulated the contents pointed at by `list1`, then that would be a different story: you would have been able to see the changes through `curr.next`.

*Caveat emptor: this applies to CPython, and might come with a couple complications when it comes to cached objects (like small ints) - but I haven't looked at it for a while. And I'm not 100% sure it applies to every Python implementation out there, but at least for your case it should.*